# Correct the connection string used for a SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

My default connection string is

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have just created a SQL Server Compact database file called `myModel.sdf` in the `App_Data` folder, and I also created several tables inside it.

I am ASP.NET newbie and I don't know how to correct the above connection string so that my application will use the created `.sdf` file or its tables. Thank you for guiding me.

Comment: Apply a bit of thinking - look at the connection string and try to think where a *.mdf filename might be already specified and changed. This has nothing to do with being a newbie and everything to do with not making the minimal effort.

Comment: Check out [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com) for all things connection-string related for any version of SQL Server

Comment: @marc_s - The question is lazy. Though a good resource, the link wouldn't help the OP as they would still need to inspect and change any connection string given on it.

Comment: Sorry, my mind is busy the whole week, i have headache since time I enter web field. I want to be a boss so i don't code down things like this.

Comment: If you don't do any sort of thinking, your chances of becoming a boss are very low.

Comment: @Oded: I get the feeling that some bosses get promoted because they can't think!  Like that pointy-haired boss in Dilbert!  :)

Comment: @MitchWheat - [The Dilbert principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dilbert_principle), yes.

Answer (score 3):

I can highly reccommed you spending some time reading about connection strings on http://connectionstrings.com/

Comment: I also recommend this, its where i go if i want to do stuff with connection strings

Answer (score 2):

I create connection string like this:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=."
                    + databasePath
                    + dbName
                    + ";Password=" + dbPassword + ";";
```